# Use a variable in a Linq expression

Tags: linq

I'm composing a Linq query where my object constructs a grid (table) down in my view.

```
filteredProducts =
    filteredProducts.Take(take)
                    .Skip(pagesToSkip)
                    .OrderBy(w => w.ProductName)
                    .ToList();
```

As per the very common pattern; the grid can 'OrderBy' different columns depending on which column header is clicked. I need to replace the hardcoded 'ProductName' so that any of the possible column names can be included. The [solution is probably based on the approach presented at  this question but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958220/how-can-i-use-linq-to-sort-by-multiple-fields) but my use-case is different enough that I haven't yet been able to implement anything. SO's auto-suggest isn't offering any other obvious which seems strange because surely this is a common problem.

I've tried the obvious:

```
var mySortColumn = "w.ProductId";
```

then:

```
.OrderBy(w => mySortColumn)
```

and get no compile or runtime complaints but no respect for the designated value either. Other variations I've tried will toss compiler errors right away.

[This article suggests I should use a SWITCH/CASE construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb513731.aspx) to build a completely different query for each of my possible 'OrderBy' clauses. While I'm not typically one to turn up my nose at a hack but; Ick.

It's almost looks like we haven't evolved all that far from the 'build a string' days of dynamic SQL days.

Comment: You can store Expressions like w => w.ProductName for each of column, and then substitute them in query `OrderBy(productColumnExpression)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `OrderBy` method takes a `Func<Type,int>` delegate. This means you can do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foos = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo { A = 1, B = 2 },
            new Foo { A = 2, B = 1 }
        };

        Func<Foo, int> a = f => f.A;
        Func<Foo, int> b = f => f.B;

        bool orderByA = false;

        Display(foos.OrderBy(orderByA ? a : b));
    }

    private static void Display(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        foos.ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return A + " " + B;
    }
}
```

If you really want to be able to sort on a property name, you need to create some code that creates an `Expression` from your `string`.