# C# How to use .OrderBy with multiple columns and decode column number to column name?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, datatables

So I'm using Datatable.net, Asp.net MVC Controller serving up Json data. 
I'm trying to do something simliar to these posts:

- [LINQ Sort by Multiple Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958220/how-can-i-use-linq-to-sort-by-multiple-fields)
- [Multi Column Sort for Datatables.net](http://activeengine.net/2011/02/09/datatablepager-now-has-multi-column-sort-capability-for-datatables-net/)

I have the following parameters from the Javascript Ajax call to the sever:

> ```
> > int iSortingCols    Number of columns to sort on
> > int iSortCol_(int)  Column being sorted on 
> >          (you will need to decode this number for your database)
> > string  sSortDir_(int)  Direction to be sorted - "desc" or "asc".
> ```

Here's my Dataset:

```
var db = new GER_MAPV_Context();
var allTags = db.TrimTables;
filteredTags = db.TrimTables.AsEnumerable();
IEnumerable<TrimTable> filteredTags;
```

//Dependent function for Sorting

```
Func<TrimTable, string> getColumnName = (
    c => getCurrentSortColumn(1) == 1 ? c.TAG :
    sortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.DESCRIPTION :
    sortColumnIndex == 3 ? c.SET_POINT :
    sortColumnIndex == 4 ? c.PRIORITY :
    sortColumnIndex == 5 ? c.LIMIT_TYPE :
    sortColumnIndex == 6 ? c.ALARM_TYPE :
    sortColumnIndex == 7 ? c.AUTOMATED_SYSTEM :
    sortColumnIndex == 8 ? c.COL_POL :
    sortColumnIndex == 9 ? c.PROPERTY :
    sortColumnIndex == 10 ? c.EQUIP_TYPE:
    sortColumnIndex == 11 ? c.P_ID :
    sortColumnIndex == 12 ? c.AREA :
    sortColumnIndex == 13 ? c.COMPLEX :
    sortColumnIndex == 14 ? c.UNIT :  //PI Unit Format Long-text
    sortColumnIndex == 15 ? c.UNIT_ : //Loop Number Format
    sortColumnIndex == 16 ? c.LOOP_TYPE : //Loop Type i.e. PI, FIT, PSV
    sortColumnIndex == 17 ? c.LOOP_ : //Loop Number
    sortColumnIndex == 18 ? c.LOOP_EXT  :
    c.UNIT
    );
```

Then I need to Sort each of these columns accordingly up to 4 sorts.

```
filteredTags.OrderBy(getColumnName).ThenByDescending(getColumnName);
//could have 1 - 4 orderby.thenby arrangements
```

the trick is I need to input "sortColumnIndex" 
(which is a number, and JSON parameter of iSortCol_1 or iSortCol_2 respectively) 
into the getColumnName Function so it return the proper column name.

I'm racking my brain here.

**Q: So what are the basic steps to do this? 
 And what is the basic jist of the LINQ  expression I'm trying to build here?**

Comment: Ah Yah This tutorial totally answers my question.
http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com/2012/02/mvc-jquery-ui-and-datatable-pluginajax.html

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280952/Multiple-Column-Sorting-by-Field-Names-Using-Linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will work for you. You just need to add a lambda function.

```
var result = filteredTags
.OrderBy(t => getColumnName(t, iSortCol_1))
.ThenBy(t => getColumnName(t, iSortCol_2));
```

But your getColumnName needs to have two input parameters (the table and the columnNum).

Update:

To include the sort column count and the descending:

```
var r = firstDesc ? 
filteredTags
.OrderByDescending(t => getColumnName(iSortCol_1))
: filteredTags
.OrderBy(t => getColumnName(iSortCol_1))



for ( var i =1;  i < colCount; i++)
{
    r = nDesc ? 
    r.ThenByDescending(t => getColumnName(iSortCol_1))
    : r.OrderBy(t => getColumnName(iSortCol_1))
}
```

Comment: Ah Yah... There we go!

Comment: What's firstDesc? stand for? I'm confused

Comment: Sorry, firstIsDescending=sSortDir(0); nDesc=sSortDir(i); etc.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here's my final code if anyone is curious:
I also found these two sites helpful:

- [Multiple Field Sorting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280952/Multiple-Column-Sorting-by-Field-Names-Using-Linq)
- [Farm Fresh Code MVC, DataTables](http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com/2012/02/mvc-jquery-ui-and-datatable-pluginajax.html#comment-form)

  ```
      //Dependent function for Sorting
      //This Functions Retrieves the Database Field Name to be used by the Orderby("Tag") function 
      // i.e. OrderBy(t => t.Area);
      // t = TrimTable
      // iSortCol = Column Number to Sort By
      Func<TrimTable, Int32, string> getColName =(
      (t, iSortCol) => iSortCol == 1 ? t.TAG :
                      iSortCol == 2 ? t.DESCRIPTION :
                      iSortCol == 3 ? t.SET_POINT :
                      iSortCol == 4 ? t.PRIORITY :
                      iSortCol == 5 ? t.LIMIT_TYPE :
                      iSortCol == 6 ? t.ALARM_TYPE :
                      iSortCol == 7 ? t.AUTOMATED_SYSTEM :
                      iSortCol == 8 ? t.COL_POL :
                      iSortCol == 9 ? t.PROPERTY :
                      iSortCol == 10 ? t.EQUIP_TYPE:
                      iSortCol == 11 ? t.P_ID :
                      iSortCol == 12 ? t.AREA :
                      iSortCol == 13 ? t.COMPLEX :
                      iSortCol == 14 ? t.UNIT :  //PI Unit Format Long-text
                      iSortCol == 15 ? t.UNIT_ : //Loop Number Format
                      iSortCol == 16 ? t.LOOP_TYPE : //Loop Type i.e. PI, FIT, PSV
                      iSortCol == 17 ? t.LOOP_ : //Loop Number
                      iSortCol == 18 ? t.LOOP_EXT  :
                      t.UNIT_
          );


     //Help Info: 
      //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958220/how-can-i-use-linq-to-sort-by-multiple-fields
      //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582725/c-sharp-how-to-use-orderby-with-multiple-columns-and-decode-column-number-to-co#21583371
      //http://activeengine.net/2011/02/09/datatablepager-now-has-multi-column-sort-capability-for-datatables-net/
      //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852(v=vs.110).aspx


      //Number of Columns to Sort
      int iSortCols = Convert.ToInt32(param.iSortingCols);
      Debug.WriteLine("Count of Sortable Columns" + iSortCols);
      //int   iSortCol_(int)  Column being sorted on (you will need to decode this number for your database)
      //string    sSortDir_(int)  Direction to be sorted - "desc" or "asc".

      //If Sort Expression Exists
      if (iSortCols > 0)
      {
          //Sorting
          string[] sSortDirection = new string[iSortCols]; // asc or desc
          Int32[] iSortColNum = new Int32[iSortCols]; //number

          //Get Sorting Parameters from MVC Controller
          for (int h = 0; h < iSortCols; h++)
          {
              //Get Sort Direction
              var s1 = "sSortDir_" + h;
              sSortDirection[h] = Convert.ToString(Request[s1]);

              //Get Sort Column Number
              var s2 = "iSortCol_" + h;
              iSortColNum[h] = Convert.ToInt32(Request[s2]);

          }

          //Build Orderby Statement
          for (int i = 0; i < iSortCols; i++)
          {
              // We need to keep the loop index, not sure why it is altered by the Linq.
              var index = i;

              //If Current Column is Ascending/Descending
              if (sSortDirection[index] == "asc")
              {
                  //Orderby / Thenby
                  orderedTags = (index == 0) ? filteredTags.OrderBy(t => getColName(t, iSortColNum[index]))
                                          : orderedTags.ThenBy(t => getColName(t, iSortColNum[index]));

              }
              else
              {
                  orderedTags = (index == 0) ? filteredTags.OrderByDescending(t => getColName(t, iSortColNum[index]))
                                         : orderedTags.ThenByDescending(t => getColName(t, iSortColNum[index]));
              }

          }

          //Return Orderby LINQ to Original Result Variable
          filteredTags = orderedTags;
      }
      else
      {
          //Default Sort if None is Selected
          filteredTags = filteredTags.OrderBy(t => t.TAG);
      }
  ```

Comment: Does it work with DateTime column ? Because user can see dd.mm.yyyy but you want to sort it by yyyy.mm.dd.